# Find label by name and set label text from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to set label text from code behind.
Here is my aspx page I have more labels as well like lbl2, lbl3..

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btn1" runat="server" onclick="btn1_Click" >
                      <img id="img1" runat="server"  width="195" height="306" alt="slider"><label id="lb11" runat="server" /></asp:LinkButton>
```

In code behind I am truing this

```
for (int i = 1; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
Label lbltest = new Label();
                lbltest = (Label)this.FindControl("lbl" + i.ToString()) as Label; 
                lbltest.Text = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i - 1]["Type"]);
}
```

But I am getting error:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'.
What should i do ? Please help!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create and set label text from code behind

```
Label lb = new Label();
lb.Text = "SomeText";
lb.Id = "LabelID";
Form.Controls.Add(lb);
```

if you want to find an already exisisting label and change the text:

```
Label lb = (Label)FindControl("LabelID");
lb.Text = "New text";
```

Answer (score 2):

The label in your code is not an ASP.NET control. You should use:

```
<asp:Label
```

rather than just

```
<label
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Label label1 = (Label)Master.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl(LabelID);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.