# C#: Looping through array of label ids (strings) and changing labels text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using C# with ASP.NET. I have a number of label controls which I have created in HTML. I want to be able to loop through each of these labels and change their text using C#. I tried using the below code, where I loop through an array of strings (each item representing the label's id), then using the FindControl function to get the label with the specific id and then change its text. However, when running the code I get the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'

My code is below:

In default.aspx:

```
<body>
    <label id="label1" runat="server"></label>
    <label id="label2" runat="server"></label>
    <label id="label3" runat="server"></label>    
</body>
```

In default.aspx.cs:

```
// below labels already created in default.aspx using HTML (as seen above)
String[] arr = {"label1", "label2", "label3"}; // each item is label's id

foreach (String item in arr)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)FindControl(item);
    lbl.Text = "new text";

}
```

Comment: Think maybe you want `<ASP:Label id="label1">` instead of `<label id="label1">`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find label by name and set label text from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538777/find-label-by-name-and-set-label-text-from-code-behind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the control from a Label to ASP:Label fixed the problem.